# How to clear the authtoken from firebase persistedinstallation.json

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

while installing the android mobile app my app i used firebase FCM , while installing the application i can see a file named persistedinstallation.json where authtoken ,FID created how to clear this data because while my testing team testing the application they said u should not save the authtoken in any files.

```
    {"Fid":"jsdksdie0e0303030Vp","Status":3,"AuthToken":"asdnkskds83729329293e8230251bWJlciI6MjU1MDQyMjI0NjV9.AB2LPV8wRQIgC_07k0OqWi8xsEg6TJ38-","TokenCreationEpochInSecs":823239283928329,"ExpiresInSecs":604800}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can keep the file as it is, as it doesn't leak any user info, those  AuthToken managed by [firebase here it's declared.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1822#issuecomment-664586312)